# Java: How to tell if API Completable Future errored out

Tags: java, future

How do I tell if a Completeable Future failed with an error? I am trying to look through Java Future Library below and find out? Not sure which one to pick.

Right now, when one succeeds, and one fails, trying to find which API had the error.

```
CompletableFuture<ProductResponse> productFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
        productAPI(productRequest)
);
CompletableFuture<VendorResponse> vendorFuture= CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
        vendorAPI.postLogin(vendorRequest)
);

try {
    CompletableFuture.allOf(productFuture , vendorFuture).join();
} catch (Exception e) {
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if a specific future failed by checking `isCompletedExceptionally()` after it's done:

```
if (productFuture.isCompletedExceptionally()) {
    System.out.println("product request failed!");
}
```

Or by catching the `ExecutionException` via `get()`:

```
try {
    productFuture.get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    System.out.println("product request failed!");
}
```

Or you can set a failure callback via `exceptionally()` or `whenComplete()`:

```
productFuture = productFuture.whenComplete(
        (res, exc) -> System.out.println("product request failed!"));
```